# Ardruino Serial.avalible not working

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have the following bit of code. it is meant to recieved data via the serial port and then print it back to the serial port.

```
char inData[20]; // Allocate some space for the string
char inChar=-1; // Where to store the character read
byte index = 0; // Index into array; where to store the character

void setup() {
// initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.write("Power On");
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
} 

char getValue()
{
index =0 ;  
int code =-1;
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  if(index < 19) // One less than the size of the array
     {
      inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
      inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
      index++; // Increment where to write next
      inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
      code=1;
      }        
    }   
  return code;
}
```

the main loop:

```
void loop() 
{

 char response = getValue();

  if(response != -1)
  {
  Serial.println("ok");
  Serial.println( inData); 
  }
```

The problem i am having which I cant figure out, is if i send it "45" it the prints :

```
"ok
4
ok
5"
```

and not  "ok 45"

Why is this?  Serial.avalible returns the number of bytes available to read, it should return 2 if i send it 45 ?

Answer (score 0):

I gett that in your loop your calling getvalue so quickly that you did not receive all the caracters already.

A simple solution for that is to send a code for the begining and the end of your message.

For instance use '\n' to say end of message.

Then modify get value to wait and continue to read until it find a '\n' as you never know how long it will take

Comment: And hope you don't get any line noise that corrupts the. \n character because then your code will wait forever.

Comment: This is true! Obviously for this a stupid timeout can save you (this is not a good solutions i know but this is simple)

Comment: @dzada, Ok i see what you are saying, but how can it execute to fast. surely it does so sequentially?  The while loop in the getValue() function should loop twice?  Would adding a delay in my main function not solve the problem?

Comment: You write the "45" in the console i guess, this is then transmitted over serial port to the arduino chip. The speed of your while loop in getvalue is good enough to be faster that the time the 2nd byte is transmitted to the chip. This communication takes some timle, and the loop executes at max speed on the arduino, It may be faster than the communications

Comment: @dzada oh ok i see what you are saying, cause the serial input also comes sequentially, and not ad 45 but as 4,5